# What are the functional differences between .profile .bash_profile and .bashrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, profile

What are the functional differences between the `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are specific to `bash`, whereas `.profile` is read by many shells in the absence of their own shell-specific config files.  (`.profile` was used by the original Bourne shell.)  `.bash_profile` or `.profile` is read by login shells, along with `.bashrc`; subshells read only `.bashrc`.  (Between job control and modern windowing systems, `.bashrc` by itself doesn't get used much.  If you use `screen` or `tmux`, screens/windows usually run subshells instead of login shells.)

The idea behind this was that one-time setup was done by `.profile` (or shell-specific version thereof), and per-shell stuff by `.bashrc`.  For example, you generally only want to load environment variables once per session instead of getting them whacked any time you launch a subshell within a session, whereas you always want your aliases (which aren't propagated automatically like environment variables are).

Other notable shell config files:

`/etc/bash_profile` (fallback `/etc/profile`) is read before the user's `.profile` for system-wide configuration, and likewise `/etc/bashrc` in subshells (no fallback for this one).  Many systems including Ubuntu also use an `/etc/profile.d` directory containing shell scriptlets, which are `.` (`source`)-ed from `/etc/profile`; the fragments here are per-shell, with `*.sh` applying to all Bourne/POSIX compatible shells and other extensions applying to that particular shell.

Comment: Mnemonic: A Pro-File is used sparingly to modify your environment and start your ignition switch, Bashrc is a splash some people spray all over your dash.

Comment: docs does not mention .bashrc being loaded in subshells. I did try '|', () and $() and none did read .bashrc file. It is loaded only on interactive and non-login shell and only when invoked by "bash" and not "sh" (same in docs). Didn't you mean a shell started from shell by saying *subshell*? Because that would be an interactive, non-login shell for which it's true that .bashrc IS read and .profile is NOT. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: In bash, login shells reads `.bash_profile` but does not read `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 131):

#### `.profile`

`.profile` is for things that are not specifically related to Bash, like environment variables `PATH` and friends, and should be available anytime.

For example, `.profile` should also be loaded when starting a graphical desktop session.

#### `.bashrc`

`.bashrc` is for the configuration of the interactive Bash usage, like Bash aliases, setting your favorite editor, setting the Bash prompt, etc.

#### `.bash_profile`

`.bash_profile` is for making sure that both the things in `.profile` and `.bashrc` are loaded for *login shells*.

For example, `.bash_profile` could be something simple like

```
. ~/.profile
. ~/.bashrc
```

If you were to omit `.bashrc`, only `.profile` would be loaded.

Answer (score 61):

According to the bash man page, `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

So, what is a login or non-login shell?

When you login (type username and password) via console, either sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: `.bash_profile` is executed to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.
But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window (xterm) inside Gnome or KDE, then `.bashrc` is executed before the window command prompt. `.bashrc` is also run when you start a new bash instance by typing `/bin/bash` in a terminal.

An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`. Other GUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.

More at: [.bash_profile vs .bashrc - by Josh Staiger](https://joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

Comment: Your answer is more accurate than the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

I resorted to the man page for this answer (`man bash`).

The three files are all used by bash in different scenarios.

**Scenario 1**: *interactive login shell*
(interactive means you can do user input.  Note this does NOT include cron jobs! A login shell is the first shell that is spawned when you login, but does not include sub-shells)
So basically this is the command prompt you get right when you login.
What will bash do?
Bash reads /etc/profile every time.
Then, it looks for ~/.bash_profile.  If it doesn't exist, it looks for ~/.bash_login.  If that doesn't exist, then it looks for ~/.profile.  But it will only read one of .bash_profile, .bash_login, and .profile.  So it will quit after it finds one and reads it.

**Scenario 2**: *interactive non-login*
(This is a shell that is started after the first login shell.  This shell is one that allows user input).
When an interactive non-login shell is started:
Bash just reads /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

**Scenario 3**: *non-interactive shell*
(for example cronjob)
When non-interactive, it doesn't load any of the files at all.  But, it does look for an environment variable called BASH_ENV which is supposed to contain the path to a file that will be executed.  So in this case, it doesn't read any of the ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile files unless you explicitly set the BASH_ENV to an absolute path.  I believe this is why you should always specify the absolute path in any cronjobs because none of the config files get executed by default.

Here is my source

From [bash(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)